# Preserving the column filter tags on navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap-table, react-table

I am using react-table (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) and I need to keep the filters active with the values that I had entered initially even on navigation from the page until I remove them myself. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You can use a global store like redux or Mobx to keep the data and populate your views from there (if you don't know how to use any global stores yet, learn now and get it over with).

**not recommended** you can pass the data you want to preserve in between routes using your navigation library. But don't do that. This approach would almost immediately start creating problems with maintainability for oyu.